# Check if input value is not the same onBlur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if the value of an input box is not the same after blur?

```
$("#username").on('blur', function() {
  $("#usertext").append("new input<br>");
})
```

Check this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xztptsdg/

Let's think that I enter "Josh" in input and after blur, will append new input box. But, user can "re-blur" the username input, and will append other input.

I want to check if the value is the same, not append new input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/xztptsdg/5/)

You can keep a global variable to store the current value of the textbox and then check whether the entered value is the same as the previous one. If not, then append the `new input` text and also set the global variable with the new one. Below is the Javascript that does this.

**JS**

```
var txt = "";
$("#username").on('blur', function() {
  if (txt != this.value) {
    $("#usertext").append("new input<br>");
    txt = this.value;
  }
})
```

I would suggest you to use `change()`. According to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/xztptsdg/7/) and below is the JS code with `change()`.

```
$("#username").change(function() {
    $("#usertext").append("new input<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/), for example:

```
$("#username").on('change', function() {
    $("#usertext").append("new input<br>");
});
```

So, there is no need to check if the value changed or not because the `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following snippet.

```js
var text = '';
$("#username").on('blur', function() {
  if(this.value != text){
    text = this.value;  
    $("#usertext").append('new input<br>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<br>
<span id="usertext"></span>
```